# Initializing constant from constant lookup table

Tags: c, constants, initializer

I have a constant lookup table

```
static const uint32_t lut [] = {0, 20, 100, 350, 560};
```

I have a struct

```
typedef struct {
    uint32_t value;
    const char * name;
} strct_t;
```

And I would like to create **global** constant instance of that struct

```
const struct_t def_myname = {
    .value = lut[DEF_MYNAME_ID],
    .name = "myname",
};
```

but I need to define `DEF_MYNAME_ID` in other place, so I have this in some header file

```
#define DEF_MYNAME_ID 3
```

This can't compile, because of this error `initializer element is not constant`

There are multiple questions in stackoverflow asking what to do with `initializer element is not constant`, but none covers my needs.

Is there a way how to do this? For example by defining `lut` as macro? I don't need it in other place.

Is there something like

```
#define LUT(a) ...
```

usabele as const initializer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, macros can do that.
This is actually a safer code, if you pick an index out of range, it won't compile.

First we define our dictionary

```
#define _val0 0
#define _val1 20
#define _val2 100
#define _val3 350
#define _val4 560
```

Now we need a `PRIMITIVE_CAT` to force expansion of the argument of the macro `LUT`.

```
#define PRIMITIVE_CAT(a, ...) a ## __VA_ARGS__
```

And finaly, the `LUT`.

```
#define LUT(X) PRIMITIVE_CAT(_val, X)
```

Now your code.

```
#define DEF_MYNAME_ID 3
const struct_t def_myname = {
    .value = LUT(DEF_MYNAME_ID),
    .name = "myname",
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're mostly out of luck, at least with plain C, as even the following wouldn't compile as a static initializer:

```
int v = ((uint32_t[]) { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 })[3];
```

FWIW, this would be fine:

```
static const uint32_t *pv = lut + DEF_MYNAME_ID;
```

as would be this (essentially the same):

```
static const uint32_t *pv = &(lut[DEF_MYNAME_ID]);
```

Also, in C++, your whole case would be fine as given.